# get input value of form without submit and put it on a variable in php

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

Here is a part of my code in a PHP file :

```
echo '<form action="verification.php" method="POST">';
echo '<label><b>Name</b></label>';
echo '<input type="text" placeholder="name" name="username" required>';
echo '<input type="submit" id="submit" value="go" ></form>';
```

How can I get the input value of the form without submitting it and put it in a variable `$var`?

My goal : when we click on submit, it opens a window with the name of the input.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You cannot. If you want to print the input without submitting the form, you'll have to use JavaScript. PHP is executed on the server side and cannot be run without form submission.

Comment: As @Niellles pointed out, you need to use JavaScript to achieve your goal. Your code would have to catch the `submit` event of the form, prevent the default behaviour and instead open the new window with the value entered in the text input.